# How to put siblings in Tikz tree on different length from root?

Tags: tikz-trees

How can I vary with the edge length of nodes on the same level? My tree is so wide it doesn't fit on a page anymore. If I would alternate with the depth of the node on depth 1, I think the tree might fit on one page.

EnergyMotivation, HealthMotivation, SleepQualityMotivation on normal distance and ShapeMotivation together with AttractivenessMotivation somewhat further away from the root.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,notitlepage]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}              
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{rotating} 

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={
        rectangle,
        black,
        draw,
        minimum size = 0em,
        edge={<-},
        l sep = 45pt,
        s sep = 1pt,
    },
    arrow label/.style={
        edge label={node [midway, font=\scriptsize\sffamily, sloped, above] {#1}}
    }
    [\textbf{MotivationProfile}, fill=green!20
        [EnergyMotivation, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
            [Low, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
                [1, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [2, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [3, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [4, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]

            ]
            [Medium, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
                [5, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [6, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
            ]
            [High, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
                [7, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [8, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [9, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [10, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
            ]
        ]
        [ShapeMotivation, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
            [Low, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
                [1, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [2, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [3, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [4, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]

            ]
            [Medium, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
                [5, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [6, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
            ]
            [High, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
                [7, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [8, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [9, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [10, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
            ]
        ]
        [HealthMotivation, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
            [Low, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
                [1, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [2, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [3, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [4, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]

            ]
            [Medium, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
                [5, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [6, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
            ]
            [High, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
                [7, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [8, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [9, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                [10, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
            ]
        ]
        [AttractivenessMotivation, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
                [Low, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
                    [1, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                    [2, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                    [3, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                    [4, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]

                ]
                [Medium, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
                    [5, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                    [6, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                ]
                [High, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
                    [7, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                    [8, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                    [9, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                    [10, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                ]
        ]
        [SleepQualityMotivation, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
                [Low, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
                    [1, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                    [2, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                    [3, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                    [4, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]

                ]
                [Medium, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
                    [5, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                    [6, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                ]
                [High, arrow label=isA, fill=green!20
                    [7, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                    [8, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                    [9, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                    [10, rounded rectangle, arrow label=isA, fill=blue!20]
                ]
        ]
    ] 
\end{forest}
\caption{Close view on the motivation profile concept}
\label{image:ontology-motivation}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please extend your code snippet to complee small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` continued with document preamble (relevant to page layout and your problem), your code fragment and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

- all distances in your `forest` are equal, difference in positioning of the nodes 7, 8, 9 and 10 is different height of node `Hight` caused by letter `g`. this can be eliminated by defining `text depth` for "green" nodes.
- in forest code blank lines are not allowed
- in mwe below is done some improvement to your code, which make your code much shorter. since in the time, when i wrote code, your document preable was not know, i use `standalone` document class. you can replace it with your preamble and add missing `sidewaysfigure` with caption (this part of code is not essential for proposed solution):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        if n children=0{rounded corners=2pt,fill=blue!20,
                        inner sep=2pt, anchor=north}%
                       {fill=green!20,
                        text depth=0.25ex}, % <--- solve your problem
        edge={{Straight Barb[length=2pt, width=2pt]}-},
        l sep = 45pt,
        s sep = 3pt,
    },
    arrow label/.style={
        edge label={node [pos=0.7, font=\scriptsize\sffamily,
                          inner sep=1pt, sloped, above] {#1}}
    }
    [\textbf{MotivationProfile},
        [EnergyMotivation, arrow label=isA
            [Low, arrow label=isA
                [1, arrow label=isA]
                [2, arrow label=isA]
                [3, arrow label=isA]
                [4, arrow label=isA]
            ]
            [Medium, arrow label=isA
                [5, arrow label=isA ]
                [6, arrow label=isA ]
            ]
            [High, arrow label=isA
                [7, arrow label=isA ]
                [8, arrow label=isA ]
                [9, arrow label=isA ]
                [10, arrow label=isA ]
            ]
        ]
        [ShapeMotivation, arrow label=isA
            [Low, arrow label=isA
                [1, arrow label=isA ]
                [2, arrow label=isA ]
                [3, arrow label=isA ]
                [4, arrow label=isA ]
            ]
            [Medium, arrow label=isA
                [5, arrow label=isA ]
                [6, arrow label=isA ]
            ]
            [High, arrow label=isA
                [7, arrow label=isA ]
                [8, arrow label=isA ]
                [9, arrow label=isA ]
                [10, arrow label=isA ]
            ]
        ]
        [HealthMotivation, arrow label=isA
            [Low, arrow label=isA
                [1, arrow label=isA ]
                [2, arrow label=isA ]
                [3, arrow label=isA ]
                [4, arrow label=isA ]
            ]
            [Medium, arrow label=isA
                [5, arrow label=isA ]
                [6, arrow label=isA ]
            ]
            [High, arrow label=isA
                [7, arrow label=isA ]
                [8, arrow label=isA ]
                [9, arrow label=isA ]
                [10, arrow label=isA ]
            ]
        ]
        [AttractivenessMotivation, arrow label=isA
                [Low, arrow label=isA
                    [1, arrow label=isA ]
                    [2, arrow label=isA ]
                    [3, arrow label=isA ]
                    [4, arrow label=isA ]
                ]
                [Medium, arrow label=isA
                    [5, arrow label=isA ]
                    [6, arrow label=isA ]
                ]
                [High, arrow label=isA
                    [7, arrow label=isA ]
                    [8, arrow label=isA ]
                    [9, arrow label=isA ]
                    [10, arrow label=isA ]
                ]
        ]
        [SleepQualityMotivation, arrow label=isA
                [Low, arrow label=isA
                    [1, arrow label=isA ]
                    [2, arrow label=isA ]
                    [3, arrow label=isA ]
                    [4, arrow label=isA ]
                ]
                [Medium, arrow label=isA
                    [5, arrow label=isA ]
                    [6, arrow label=isA ]
                ]
                [High, arrow label=isA
                    [7, arrow label=isA ]
                    [8, arrow label=isA ]
                    [9, arrow label=isA ]
                    [10, arrow label=isA ]
                ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Splendid! Indeed, nice and clean code!